# Apply d3force to a network with multiple groups

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, d3-force-directed

I am a beginner at d3 hence this question... I have a network with a bunch of nodes, links and groups which looks something like below:

I want to implement a d3-force on it so that each group has its own force and when one group is acted on, the other group doesnt get affected.

Notice how node 5, has group 0 since its a singleton. So all singletons will have group 0.

```
network = {
  "nodes" : [
    {
      "id":0,
      "x":0,
      "y":0,
      "group":1
    },
    {
      "id":1,
      "x":11,
      "y":-11,
      "group":1
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "x":22,
      "y":-22,
      "group":1
    },
    {
      "id":3,
      "x":33,
      "y":-33,
      "group":2
    },
    {
      "id":4,
      "x":44,
      "y":-44,
      "group":2
    },
    {
      "id":5,
      "x":55,
      "y":-55,
      "group":0
    }],
  "links" : [
    {
      "from": 0,
      "to"  : 1
    },
    {
      "from": 1,
      "to"  : 2
    },
    {
      "from": 3,
      "to"  : 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's not exactly what you are asking here, but it might get you started, here is a working example of a grouped force layout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071493/d3-v4-force-simulation-grouped/43489191

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) So the thing is, I have the all the nodes laid out nicely with their respective groups.... the problem is once everything is loaded, I need to be able to attach force to each group so that they dont interfere with each other... Its been turning to be harder than I thought :( I was wondering if it was as easy as to attach a force to a group and done

Comment: another approach could be to fix the position of all other groups when a groups is interacted with using `fx` and `fy` properties

Comment: :( really sorry for my naiveté but how wud I do that? Sorry am very new to D3

Comment: posting a complete code sample or a fiddle would help

Comment: Here you go... https://jsfiddle.net/pdubey84/ypgo7af8/ you might have to scroll the result window to see the full network.... So to try it out, just try to drag the bottom big network onto itself... notice how it wouldnt untangle.... I would want it to untangle but applying forces just stars moving everything as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143581/discussion-between-ideate-and-thedude).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to go about it, note I had to re-rewrite the grouping function as your's has a bug in it.

```js
var networkData = {
  "nodes": [{
    "id": "0",
    "x": 1509.9862,
    "y": -609.1013,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "x": 1645.9578,
    "y": -85.06705,
    "row_count": 3
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "x": 1948.1533,
    "y": -469.3646,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "x": 1490.8839,
    "y": -705.9929,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "4",
    "x": 2370.9739,
    "y": -114.61766,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "5",
    "x": 1788.3419,
    "y": -460.89978,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "6",
    "x": 1601.6083,
    "y": -459.14755,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "7",
    "x": 1967.1221,
    "y": -179.95412,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "8",
    "x": 2305.796,
    "y": -398.09714,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "9",
    "x": 2075.197,
    "y": -119.19522,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "10",
    "x": 144.70703,
    "y": -492.124,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "11",
    "x": 1782.7756,
    "y": -95.29288,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "12",
    "x": 2490.2249,
    "y": -395.42737,
    "row_count": 4
  }, {
    "id": "13",
    "x": 1434.9111,
    "y": -507.22018,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "14",
    "x": 1918.9606,
    "y": -132.97313,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "15",
    "x": 150.78381,
    "y": -375.75558,
    "row_count": 4
  }, {
    "id": "16",
    "x": 117.40755,
    "y": -313.40042,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "17",
    "x": 128.44798,
    "y": -569.65533,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "18",
    "x": 2241.112,
    "y": -397.3375,
    "row_count": 5
  }, {
    "id": "19",
    "x": 93.45022,
    "y": -510.2351,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "20",
    "x": 2554.5647,
    "y": -395.42737,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "21",
    "x": 1552.0585,
    "y": -175.00697,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "22",
    "x": 1839.4581,
    "y": -137.50499,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "23",
    "x": 88.88344,
    "y": -374.78418,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "24",
    "x": 1588.2749,
    "y": -583.3556,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "25",
    "x": 115.34364,
    "y": -439.38092,
    "row_count": 5
  }, {
    "id": "26",
    "x": 1527.4338,
    "y": -425.7689,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "27",
    "x": 1466.7098,
    "y": -580.9009,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "28",
    "x": 1614.1482,
    "y": -508.55847,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "29",
    "x": 1653.5695,
    "y": -705.9929,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "30",
    "x": 1555.2239,
    "y": -705.9929,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "31",
    "x": 2226.4775,
    "y": -111.886284,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "32",
    "x": 1458.8619,
    "y": -462.99728,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "33",
    "x": 1541.3425,
    "y": -599.3965,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "34",
    "x": 1572.1593,
    "y": -445.52554,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "35",
    "x": 1804.5553,
    "y": -705.9929,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "36",
    "x": 2299.7493,
    "y": -113.641975,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "37",
    "x": 1447.5342,
    "y": -536.6993,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "38",
    "x": 1633.1509,
    "y": -212.4338,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "39",
    "x": 1782.9479,
    "y": -406.7332,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "40",
    "x": 1955.5413,
    "y": -705.9929,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "41",
    "x": 2151.4285,
    "y": -111.490974,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "42",
    "x": 1598.4803,
    "y": -553.35645,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "43",
    "x": 1500.1262,
    "y": -441.0764,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "44",
    "x": 1496.883,
    "y": -587.66406,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "45",
    "x": 1596.4176,
    "y": -483.6955,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "46",
    "x": 1455.5319,
    "y": -492.96527,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "47",
    "x": 1563.5104,
    "y": -579.53015,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "48",
    "x": 2037.2152,
    "y": -292.1214,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "49",
    "x": 282.7343,
    "y": -516.7465,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "50",
    "x": 167.14136,
    "y": -428.0224,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "51",
    "x": 2003.0924,
    "y": -437.64548,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "52",
    "x": 99.81963,
    "y": -175.3665,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "53",
    "x": 179.92572,
    "y": -468.74872,
    "row_count": 3
  }, {
    "id": "54",
    "x": 1717.0072,
    "y": -705.9929,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "55",
    "x": 2007.9512,
    "y": -233.56764,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "56",
    "x": 1542.7771,
    "y": -445.58582,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "57",
    "x": 1617.18,
    "y": -149.27104,
    "row_count": 5
  }, {
    "id": "58",
    "x": 1469.2253,
    "y": -555.9452,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "59",
    "x": 1595.1055,
    "y": -524.9397,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "60",
    "x": 1484.0056,
    "y": -464.2597,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "61",
    "x": 1523.9562,
    "y": -581.0812,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "62",
    "x": 2425.8848,
    "y": -395.42737,
    "row_count": 4
  }, {
    "id": "63",
    "x": 108.56919,
    "y": -243.38808,
    "row_count": 4
  }, {
    "id": "64",
    "x": 1867.9934,
    "y": -705.9929,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "65",
    "x": 1996.9839,
    "y": -123.64043,
    "row_count": 3
  }, {
    "id": "66",
    "x": 1948.1533,
    "y": -405.92636,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "67",
    "x": 1572.0945,
    "y": -470.88098,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "68",
    "x": 1465.1875,
    "y": -518.3188,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "69",
    "x": 1572.8579,
    "y": -554.43756,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "70",
    "x": 2106.5273,
    "y": -705.9929,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "71",
    "x": 1519.5193,
    "y": -458.15424,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "72",
    "x": 1494.6997,
    "y": -561.67957,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "73",
    "x": 1579.804,
    "y": -504.15784,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "74",
    "x": 1482.025,
    "y": -489.7116,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "75",
    "x": 2175.6614,
    "y": -396.56552,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "76",
    "x": 1541.8685,
    "y": -563.2375,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "77",
    "x": 1547.088,
    "y": -472.80585,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "78",
    "x": 1485.3854,
    "y": -532.9362,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "79",
    "x": 89.103745,
    "y": -110.00311,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "80",
    "x": 1555.3121,
    "y": -116.60735,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "81",
    "x": 1426.544,
    "y": -705.9929,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "82",
    "x": 1566.833,
    "y": -530.323,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "83",
    "x": 1688.4487,
    "y": -172.91998,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "84",
    "x": 68.698006,
    "y": -573.6171,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "85",
    "x": 1764.1693,
    "y": -158.18617,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "86",
    "x": 219.68867,
    "y": -397.56903,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "87",
    "x": 1730.5239,
    "y": -424.70016,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "88",
    "x": 1837.7125,
    "y": -415.37985,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "89",
    "x": 2439.1343,
    "y": -114.35799,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "90",
    "x": 1852.3489,
    "y": -475.04614,
    "row_count": 3
  }, {
    "id": "91",
    "x": 1715.4718,
    "y": -70.03096,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "92",
    "x": 2018.9792,
    "y": -705.9929,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "93",
    "x": 2169.9653,
    "y": -705.9929,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "94",
    "x": 1508.6908,
    "y": -480.54773,
    "row_count": 4
  }, {
    "id": "95",
    "x": 1699.9895,
    "y": -126.77199,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "96",
    "x": 2110.977,
    "y": -395.80646,
    "row_count": 3
  }, {
    "id": "97",
    "x": 2123.8252,
    "y": -164.62895,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "98",
    "x": 1517.4421,
    "y": -551.2502,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "99",
    "x": 266.0747,
    "y": -450.88815,
    "row_count": 2
  }, {
    "id": "100",
    "x": 1555.2823,
    "y": -497.76593,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "101",
    "x": 1497.4402,
    "y": -510.5418,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "102",
    "x": 1542.789,
    "y": -536.3863,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "103",
    "x": 1528.8363,
    "y": -494.63577,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "104",
    "x": 1515.9209,
    "y": -525.9001,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "105",
    "x": 1526.9814,
    "y": -515.76776,
    "row_count": 1
  }, {
    "id": "106",
    "x": 1737.522,
    "y": -129.01044,
    "row_count": 2
  }],
  "links": [{
    "from": 1,
    "to": 57
  }, {
    "from": 1,
    "to": 91
  }, {
    "from": 2,
    "to": 51
  }, {
    "from": 2,
    "to": 66
  }, {
    "from": 3,
    "to": 30
  }, {
    "from": 3,
    "to": 81
  }, {
    "from": 4,
    "to": 36
  }, {
    "from": 4,
    "to": 89
  }, {
    "from": 5,
    "to": 87
  }, {
    "from": 5,
    "to": 88
  }, {
    "from": 5,
    "to": 90
  }, {
    "from": 7,
    "to": 14
  }, {
    "from": 7,
    "to": 55
  }, {
    "from": 7,
    "to": 65
  }, {
    "from": 8,
    "to": 18
  }, {
    "from": 9,
    "to": 41
  }, {
    "from": 9,
    "to": 65
  }, {
    "from": 9,
    "to": 97
  }, {
    "from": 10,
    "to": 25
  }, {
    "from": 10,
    "to": 50
  }, {
    "from": 10,
    "to": 53
  }, {
    "from": 11,
    "to": 22
  }, {
    "from": 11,
    "to": 85
  }, {
    "from": 11,
    "to": 91
  }, {
    "from": 11,
    "to": 106
  }, {
    "from": 12,
    "to": 20
  }, {
    "from": 12,
    "to": 62
  }, {
    "from": 14,
    "to": 22
  }, {
    "from": 14,
    "to": 65
  }, {
    "from": 15,
    "to": 16
  }, {
    "from": 15,
    "to": 23
  }, {
    "from": 15,
    "to": 25
  }, {
    "from": 15,
    "to": 50
  }, {
    "from": 15,
    "to": 86
  }, {
    "from": 16,
    "to": 23
  }, {
    "from": 16,
    "to": 63
  }, {
    "from": 17,
    "to": 19
  }, {
    "from": 17,
    "to": 84
  }, {
    "from": 18,
    "to": 75
  }, {
    "from": 19,
    "to": 25
  }, {
    "from": 19,
    "to": 84
  }, {
    "from": 21,
    "to": 57
  }, {
    "from": 21,
    "to": 80
  }, {
    "from": 22,
    "to": 85
  }, {
    "from": 23,
    "to": 25
  }, {
    "from": 25,
    "to": 50
  }, {
    "from": 25,
    "to": 53
  }, {
    "from": 29,
    "to": 54
  }, {
    "from": 31,
    "to": 36
  }, {
    "from": 31,
    "to": 41
  }, {
    "from": 35,
    "to": 64
  }, {
    "from": 38,
    "to": 57
  }, {
    "from": 38,
    "to": 83
  }, {
    "from": 39,
    "to": 87
  }, {
    "from": 39,
    "to": 88
  }, {
    "from": 40,
    "to": 92
  }, {
    "from": 41,
    "to": 97
  }, {
    "from": 48,
    "to": 55
  }, {
    "from": 49,
    "to": 99
  }, {
    "from": 50,
    "to": 53
  }, {
    "from": 50,
    "to": 86
  }, {
    "from": 51,
    "to": 66
  }, {
    "from": 52,
    "to": 63
  }, {
    "from": 52,
    "to": 79
  }, {
    "from": 57,
    "to": 80
  }, {
    "from": 57,
    "to": 83
  }, {
    "from": 70,
    "to": 93
  }, {
    "from": 75,
    "to": 96
  }, {
    "from": 83,
    "to": 85
  }, {
    "from": 83,
    "to": 95
  }, {
    "from": 83,
    "to": 106
  }, {
    "from": 85,
    "to": 95
  }, {
    "from": 85,
    "to": 106
  }, {
    "from": 86,
    "to": 99
  }, {
    "from": 88,
    "to": 90
  }, {
    "from": 91,
    "to": 106
  }, {
    "from": 95,
    "to": 106
  }],
  "node_count": 107,
  "link_count": 77
}


/* creating groups */
// union-find is a data structure that can union two sets and check
// whether two element in the same set.

var rootNode = {};

function group2(nodes, links) {
  nodes.forEach((n, i) => n._gid = i + 1);

  const nodeMap = nodes.reduce((result, node) => {
    result[node.id] = node;
    return result
  }, {});

  const linkedNodes = (node, group) => {
    return links.filter(link => link.source == node.id || link.target == node.id)
      .map(link => nodeMap[link.source] === node ? nodeMap[link.target] : nodeMap[link.source])
      .filter(n => n.group != group)
  }

  const infect = (node, group) => {
    node.group = group;
    linkedNodes(node, group).map(n => infect(n, group))
  }

  let n = nodes.find(node => !node.group);
  while (n) {
    infect(n, n._gid);
    n = nodes.find(node => !node.group)
  }
}
/*
function group(nodes, links) {
  // create n set with each set has the node as its only element
  links.forEach(function(link, i) {
    link.source = link.from;
    link.target = link.to;
  });

  nodes.forEach(function(node, i) {
    node.weight = 1;
    rootNode[node.id] = node.id;
  });

  // union each set that has a link between them
  links.forEach(function(link, i) {
    union(link.from, link.to);
  });

  // for each unioned set, group nodes together
  var id = 1;
  var groupIdCnt = {};
  var groupIds = {};
  var groups = {};

  nodes.forEach(function(node, i) {
    var f = find(node.id);
    if (typeof groupIds[f] === 'undefined') {
      groupIds[f] = id;
      groupIdCnt[id] = 1;
      id++;
    } else {
      groupIdCnt[groupIds[f]]++;
    }

    if (groupIdCnt[groupIds[f]] === 1) {
      node['group'] = 0;
      //console.log(node)
    } else {
      node['group'] = groupIds[f];
      //console.log(node)
    }

    if (typeof groups[node['group']] === 'undefined') {
      groups[node['group']] = [];
    }
    groups[node['group']].push(node);
  });

  return Object.values(groups);

}

// find rootNode of each set
function find(node) {
  // if it is the root, return
  if (rootNode[node] === node) {
    return node;
  }
  // if not, find the rootNode and point to it
  rootNode[node] = find(rootNode[node]);
  return rootNode[node];
}

// update the rootNode of set which includes node1 to the rootNode of set which includes node 2
function union(node1, node2) {
  rootNode[find(node1)] = find(node2);
} */

var links = networkData.links;
var nodes = networkData.nodes;

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  nodes[i].level = 1;
}

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].source = links[i].from;
  links[i].target = links[i].to;
}

var groups = group2(nodes, links)





/** ====== D3 FORCE CODE =======*/
function getNodeColor(node, neighbors) {
  return node.level === 1 ? 'red' : 'gray'
}


function getLinkColor(node, link) {
  return isNeighborLink(node, link) ? 'green' : '#000'
}

var width = 600
var height = 600
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
var svg = d3.select('svg')
svg.attr('width', width).attr('height', height)

// simulation setup with all forces
var linkForce = d3
  .forceLink()
  .id(function(link) {
    return link.id
  })
  .strength(function(link) {
    return 1
  })

var chargeForce = d3.forceManyBody()
  .strength(function(node) {
    if (links.find(link => link.source == node.id || link.target == node.id)) {
      return -100
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  }).distanceMax([100])

var simulation = d3
  .forceSimulation()
  .force('link', linkForce)
  .force('charge', chargeForce)
  .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))


var dragDrop = d3.drag().on('start', function(node) {
  simulation.nodes().forEach(n => {
    if (n.group != node.group) {
      n.fx = n.x
      n.fy = n.y
    }
  })

}).on('drag', function(node) {
  simulation.alphaTarget(0.7).restart()
  node.fx = d3.event.x
  node.fy = d3.event.y
}).on('end', function(node) {
  simulation.nodes().forEach(node => {
    node.fx = null
    node.fy = null
  })
  simulation.alphaTarget(0).restart()
})

var linkElements = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "links")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)
  .attr("stroke", "rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2)")

var nodeElements = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("fill", d => color(d.group))
  .call(dragDrop)



simulation.nodes(nodes).on('tick', () => {
  nodeElements
    .attr('cx', function(node) {
      return node.x
    })
    .attr('cy', function(node) {
      return node.y
    })

  linkElements
    .attr('x1', function(link) {
      return link.source.x
    })
    .attr('y1', function(link) {
      return link.source.y
    })
    .attr('x2', function(link) {
      return link.target.x
    })
    .attr('y2', function(link) {
      return link.target.y
    })
})

simulation.force("link").links(links)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="1000" height="600"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @thedude... just one small question... If you notice the bigger network at the bottom... If I drag it on top of itself, it doesnt open up again... is there someway to avoid that? as in the network should open up if dragged onto itself?

Comment: @ideate I've updated the example to show a direction for this

Comment: Thanks a lot @thedude... this works perfect... However while stress testing it I got an error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded... for >4K nodes and ~15K links... I believe its in the grouping logic.... apart from that it works perfect